# How to pad Fortran floating point output with leading zeros?

Tags: floating-point, formatting, fortran

I have some floating point numbers that I need to output from a Fortran program.  Let's say the maximum number could be 999.9999 and they are all non-negative.  I need zero-padding in front of all numbers less than 100.

For instance, if I have 25.6893782, 245.354567, and 1.2345678, I need to print them out in a form something like

```
025.6894
245.3546
001.2346
```

How can I do this?  It would be fairly easy with the `T` edit descriptor if I knew that, for instance, all numbers would be between 10 and 99, something like that.  But there is no way for me to know that ahead of time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me

```
real :: areal
```

then

```
write(*,'(i3.3,f0.6)') int(areal),areal-int(areal)
```

Comment: while continuing to think on it, I came up with something like this, but your way is much more elegant.  Thanks.

Comment: This method will fail with numbers such as `2.999999999999` Due to rounding this will turn awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Zero-padding can be performed for integer fields, so if you printed the result as two separate fields you might be able to make it happen. Here's a way that is less than pretty, but works. Say `x` is the value you want to print:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION x
CHARACTER*6 y

x = 123.4567

WRITE(y,'(F6.4)') x-int(x)


WRITE(*,'(I3.3,A5)') int(x), y(2:5)
```

`y` is declared as a `CHARACTER*6` because it needs to hold the fractional part of your number (4 decimal places), a leading zero, and a decimal point. This can be easily changed if you want to show more decimal places, though it would be trickier if you wanted to show a variable number of decimal places.

The `I3.3` field descriptor means "print an integer with a maximum field width of 3 and pad left with zeroes so that there are always 3 digits". When printing out the value we take `y(2:5)` to strip off the leading zero.

Happy coding!

Comment: I came up with something similar.  You and I are basically doing what High Performance Mark did, but his way is much more compact.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I saw High Performance Mark's fix and I agree. I didn't know about the '0' width specifier but it's a much better solution. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick I used to use in MS BASIC on the Commodore PETs in the late 70s.  The code has been modified for negative numbers.  If you would like positive numbers to have a leading +, just change the last character of signchr to '+'

```
subroutine leadingzero(x)
   real x
   character(len=16) str
   character, dimension(3):: signchr = (/'-', ' ', ' ' /)
   write(str,'(F9.4)') 1000.0 + abs(x)
   write(*,*) signchr(int(sign(1.0,x)) + 2), str(2:) ! drop the 1
end subroutine leadingzero

program main
   call leadingzero(0.01)
   call leadingzero(0.1)
   call leadingzero(2.532)
   call leadingzero(9.9999)
   call leadingzero(9.999999)
   call leadingzero(10.987)
   call leadingzero(123.456)
   call leadingzero(0.0)
   call leadingzero(-0.01)
   call leadingzero(-0.1)
   call leadingzero(-2.532)
   call leadingzero(-9.9999)
   call leadingzero(-9.999999)
   call leadingzero(-10.987)
   call leadingzero(-123.456)
end program
```

**Edit - returning result in a string**

```
subroutine leadingzerostr(x, str_temp)
    real x
    character(*) str_temp
    character(len=10) str
    character, dimension(3):: signchr = (/'-', ' ', ' ' /)
    write(str,'(F10.4)') 10000.0 + abs(x)
    str_temp = str
    str_temp(1:1) = signchr(int(sign(1.0,x)) + 2)
end subroutine leadingzerostr
```

Comment: Can you provide solution if the value is negative?

Comment: What sort of result are you expecting?  It prints -000.01 for -ve, 000.01 for +ve.

Comment: Is there a chance to show how we can write `signchr(int(sign(1.0,x)) + 2), str(2:)` , for example, `str_temp`, which is a `character type` with lenght of `0000.0000`?

Comment: The result is blank character. Try to make a function with `str_temp` like character result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to the method of [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888581/8344060) is to do use the `TL` and `TR` position-edit-descriptors. First print the float with `Fw.d`, move *w* positions back, print the integer with padding zeros and width *w − d*, move *d + 1* positions forward.

```
write (*, '(F6.3,TL6,I2.2,TR4)') f,int(f)
```

The problem this method and the method of [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888581/8344060) have is rounding. The following program demonstrates this:

```
program test_rounding
  double precision :: f
  f = 6 - 1D-6
  ! default compiler dependent rounding :: gfortran NEAREST
  write (*, '(F6.3,TL6,I2.2,TR4)') f,int(f)
  write (*, '(I2.2,F0.3)') int(f), f-int(f)
  write (*, '(I2.2,F4.3)') int(f), f-int(f)
  ! rounding to ZERO
  write (*, '(I2.2,RZ,F4.3)') int(f), f-int(f)
  write (*, '(RZ,F6.3,TL6,I2.2,TR4)') f,int(f)
end program
```

```
05.000          < WRONG
051.000         < VERY WRONG
05****          < EUH
05.999          < OFF BY 0.001
05.999          < OFF BY 0.001
```

The last method might be of interest, but it is not really the expected value. However, it has the same accuracy.

The following two methods work as expected, but it is required to do manual manipulate the numbers with the respected accuracy. This is not what one would expect:

```
program test_rounding
  double precision :: f
  f = 6 - 1D-6
  ! manual manipulation
  write (*,'(I2.2,".",I3.3)') nint(f*1D3)/1000, mod(nint(f*1D3),1000)
  write (*,'(F6.3,TL6,I2.2,TR4)') f,nint(f*1D3)/1000
end program
```

Both return `06.000`

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is an [edit descriptor](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Edit+descriptors) that does what you want, but you could simulate it with an `if`-statement:

```
if(var < 10) then
   write(*,'(a,f6.4)') '00',var
else if(var < 100) then
   write(*,'(a,f7.4)') '0',var
else
   write(*,'(f8.4)') var
endif
```

Comment: If a value is nearly 10, say 9.999999, will the `write` statement format it as “10.0000”, thus producing output of “0010.0000” instead of the desired “010.0000”?

Comment: It will give the desired `010.0000`, but if you have `9.9999`, it will output `009.9999`.

Comment: How does that work? Would not 9.999999 pass the test `var < 10`, resulting in writing “00” followed by “10.0000”?

Comment: I just tested it & it worked that way; I presume it is due to the precision (using `REAL`). If I use `9.99999`, it returns `00******`.